# Framwork7 Popover problem on Android View

Tags: android, html-framework-7

I Face problem on android device when i preview it's on iphone it's show well But,
After preview on android it looks like not the right way.

I am using Framwork7(Version 4) for Frontend Development.

Any one helped me to solved this problem i need same view for both devic, like iphone.
[image]
[image]

Comment: did you tried it real device?

Comment: Yes i check it on real device and it looks as above screenshot.

Comment: You should provide the code in order to get consistent help.